# No carga el frontend cuando se accede desde fuera del servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una aplicación web .NET desarrollada con C# MVC4.
Esta alojada en un IIS en corriendo en Windows Server 2012, y funcionando, siempre y cuando se accededida desde el servidor de la siguiente manera :

> http://localhost/controlador/metodo

Pero cuando accedo desde fuera del servidor

> http://IPServidor/controlador/metodo

No logro hacer que se carge bien todo el contenido HTML, realmente no carga nada, sólo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> { Layout = null; } Error. Error al procesar la solicitud.

Cabe destacar que ya revisé las rutas y configuraciones del sistema, instale en la carpeta que corresponde, pero aún así no logro ver la interfaz desde afuera.

¿Podrán ayudar a encontrar el problema?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Si puedes acceder dentro del servidor pero no fuera me suena que es un problema de red. Puedes comprobarlo ejecutando un comando telnet desde la maquina a la que quieres acceder al sitio de la siguiente manera:

```
telnet IPServidor 80
```

Si has especificado otro puerto para el sitio de IIS debes colocarlo en lugar de 80. Si te da un mensaje de error ya sea porque el servidor no es accesible desde la maquina o porque el servidor bloquea las peticiones con el puerto especificado.